# How to loop though multiple http post requests in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, loops, asynchronous

I have an array of objects that are to be passed to a mongoDB model which accepts one object at a time, I tried to loop the http post requests but as it is asynchronous, that doesn't work. Any other solution?

```
for (let entry of ingredients) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(entry);
    console.log(body);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/shopping-list', body, {headers: headers})
        .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error));

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can only return from a function once. Do you want to make these requests in series or parallel? Read the RxJS docs for the various combination operators.

Comment: I want to make the requests in series(one after the other)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to make the requests in series, try [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap)

```ts
Observable.from(ingredients)
    .concatMap(entry => this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/shopping-list', entry))
    .subscribe(
        response => console.log(response), //do something with responses
        error => console.error(error), // so something on error
        () => console.info("All requests done") // do something when all requests are done
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! helped me out

Comment: I think it's better use forkJoin than concatMap (concatMap wait to completed one call after make the second one)

Comment: Looks like this works as follows now:

import { from as observableFrom } from 'rxjs';

 observableFrom(accs).pipe(
        concatMap(entry => this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/shopping-list', entry))
    ).subscribe(
        response => console.log(response), //do something with responses
        error => console.error(error), // so something on error
        () => console.info("All requests done") // do something when all requests are done
    );